# How to add and remove a Scriptable Object to a List

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Without dragging them to the inspector. 
I want to learn how to do this using code. 
The Scriptable Objects are the same but the values on them have been modified using the inspector.

(e.g. 'Enemy' scriptable object has a 'string name' and 'int power' inside. I made new ones based on this called Bob power: 5, Mike power 1 etc..)

I want to be able to add or remove 'Bob' and 'Mike' in the list.

Comment: Did you figured it out how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put them inside a "Resources" folder and load them all by path path and type. The file structure can be something like this:

[image]

And assuming you have a `ScriptableObject` called `Enemy` which is the type of `Bob` and `Mike`, you load them like this:

```
Enemy[] enemies = Resources.LoadAll<Enemy>("Enemies");
```

Inside `enemies` variable, you will have all enemies inside the folder "Enemies" (relative to "Resources" folder). The `<Enemy>` part will ensure only `Enemy` types will be returned (even if you have other types inside the same folder) and the returned type will be the one you want (`Enemy[]`).

After that, you can tranform it into a `List<Enemy>` and manipulate as you wish.